# navigate do differents pages in the case of a listview.builder

Tags: flutter, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I want to navigate to different pages from the floatingActionBotton like what the code shows. So, when I select an item I want to go to the page of the item selected and i have  the lists made with listview.builder, so what's the solution?

```
class Selectclass {
  final String selectedclasse ;
  final String quizimage;
  final String quizdetails ;
  Selectclass ({
  required this.selectedclasse ,
 required this.quizimage,
 required this.quizdetails,
});
} 

final List<Selectclass> quizclasses = [
    Selectclass(selectedclasse: "title", quizimage: "assets/virus.png" , quizdetails: "ViralQuiz()"),
    Selectclass(selectedclasse: "title1", quizimage: "assets/virus.png" , quizdetails: "ViralQuiz()"),]
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../contants/quizlist.dart';

class QuiZhome extends StatefulWidget {
  const QuiZhome({super.key});

  @override
  State<QuiZhome> createState() => _QuiZhomeState();
}

class _QuiZhomeState extends State<QuiZhome> {
  int selectedService = -1;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: selectedService>= 0 ? FloatingActionButton
      (onPressed: (){
        
      },
      child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios, size: 20,),
      ) : null,
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return [
            const SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only( top: 120, right: 20 , left: 20),
                child: Text('Choisissez une classe pour commencer', 
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 36 ,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                ),)
                , ),
            )
          ];
        }, body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 20.0,
                    mainAxisSpacing: 20.0,
                  ), 
                  itemCount: quizclasses.length ,
                  itemBuilder: (context , index){
                    return serviceContainer(
                      quizclasses[index].quizimage,
                      quizclasses[index].selectedclasse,
                      index,
                      quizclasses[index].selectedclasse
                    );            }))
            ],

          ), ),
        ) ,
    );
  }
  serviceContainer(String image, String name, int index , String quizdetails) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (selectedService == index) {
            selectedService = -1;
          } else {
            selectedService = index;
          }
        });
      },
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: selectedService == index ? Colors.blue.shade50 : Colors.grey.shade100,
          border: Border.all(
            color: selectedService == index ? Colors.blue : Colors.blue.withOpacity(0),
            width: 2.0,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(image, height: 80),
            const SizedBox(height: 20,),
            Text(name, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),)
          ]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to make it with index, but it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the data through **Constructor**

```
class DestinationPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final SelectClass selectClass;

  const DestinationPage({Key? key,this.selectClass}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Now, to push to Destination Page with selected data, just add this code to onPressed:

```
Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => DestinationPage(quizclasses[selectedService])),
     );
```